# Subversion and Dreamweaver experience

Tags: svn, dreamweaver

How can Subversion be used with [Dreamweaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Dreamweaver)? I have a decent version control system in place, but I've heard the SVN makes life a lot easier - so I'm always trying to streamline.

I still use [CS3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Creative_Suite#Creative_Suite_3) so I'm not interested in using a Dreamweaver plugin -- I'd like to leave Dreamweaver out of the equation and deal with just the files.  I've tried TortioseSVN in the past and found it frustrating, but recently I've decided that maybe it's time to try it again.

Comment: Although I have no experience in using SVN together with Dreamweaver, I'd be interested why you found TSVN frustrating?

Comment: I found it hard to keep track of what was in/out.  I started using SmartSVN and I'm getting the hang of svn now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Dreamweaver, but SVN is great with [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) 6.9. It really makes your life easy and NetBeans is free as well. This is one link to configure your Dreamweaver to use SVNs,
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/using_subversion_pt2.html

Believe me, I was using Dreamweaver before I came across NetBeans, and I left Dreamweaver aside. And NetBeans has lots of plugins like SVN, auto syntax check and autocomplete for most of languages.

Comment: Really? I really like DW and I do build with .dwt.  Do you still use .dwt's in NetBeans.  I do my own coding so I really only use DW for its file management features, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like using Git instead of SVN for version control.  It's easier to manage branches and updates. At work we used Subversion for Eclipse for a while, but then we switched to Git. It's soo much easier to work with. You would be running Git separately from Dreamweaver, but it's quick and painless once you get your repositories set up.

http://git-scm.com/